# Set Browser Timezone in PhantomJS Pre-Built

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS prebuilt as a child process in my nodejs code, and need to set a TZ for the browser every time it is rasterized.

It is executed as a child process, as below:

```
childProcess.execFile(binPath, childArgs, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
// handle results 
});
```

There's no way to specify TZ while calling the function.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: You could set it up in your environment like `TZ=Europe/London node index.js`. Could be included in a npm script.

Comment: Am using PhantomJS as a child process and it would be dependent on user input, the nodejs parent will have to run on server time.

Comment: If you find my my answer sufficient then you should accept it.

Comment: Give me a minute @E.Sundin am working on it, will definitely accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go! Using the [options argument of the execFile function](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) and adding the custom `TZ=Europe/London` to the environment of the child process.

## index.js

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile
const env = Object.assign(process.env, { 'TZ': 'Europe/London' })
const child = execFile('./env-test.js', { env }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

## env-test.js (should be executable `chmod +x env-test.js`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log(new Date().toString())
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!